# orthogonal triangular decomposition and ordinary least squares

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

I have just come across orthogonal triangular decomposition whilst looking at ordinary least squares regression. I'm not quite sure how this is being used though to find a solution.

In my example I have a matrix **x** (100 x 2) and a vector **y** (100 x 1). Then looking at the code in MATLAB it applies the QR decomposition to my **x** matrix. I am returned a **Q matrix** & a square 2x2 **R matrix**. I do not know what the **R** matrix is telling me?

The formulas below then follow,

```
xpxi = (R' * R)\Identity Matrix    (matlab notation: (r'*r)\eye(2))
beta = xpxi*(x'*y)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key to this is that the matrix, $Q$ is orthonormal. One of the several really nice properties of orthonormal matrices is that $Q^TQ = I$. With that in mind...

$$\begin{align}X\beta &= Y\\X^TX\beta &=X^TY\\ \beta &= (X^TX)^{-1}X^TY \end{align}$$

but, $X = QR$ so...
$$\begin{align}\beta &= ((QR)^TQR)^{-1}X^TY\\ \beta &= (R^TQ^TQR)^{-1}X^TY\\\beta &= (R^TR)^{-1}X^TY\\ \end{align}$$

Why do they do it this way? Suppose that $X$ is $n \times p$ and that $n \gg p$. Then computing the $QR$ decomposition requires (substantially?) fewer floating point operations than multiplying out $X^TX$. Note that matrix $Q$ is $n\times p$ and matrix $R$ is $p\times p$.